# Cmake and ninja rebuild unnecessary files

Tags: c++, build, cmake, llvm, ninja

I am starting a Clang tool project, so I built the **LLVM/Clang** from source code using **Cmake** and **ninja**. There are two folders -- `src/` and `build/`. Then I created my project folder as **src/tools/clang/tools/extra/my-tool** and added `add_subdirectory(my-tool)` to the **tools/clang/tools/extra/CMakeLists.txt**. However, every time I modify the file under my project folder and run `ninja` under **build/**, the system sometimes only builds the modified file but sometimes rebuilds all files (more than 3000 tasks), which is very slow. I am wondering what causes the rebuilding?

BTW, the situation also happens when I modify another project, which uses the Google's Bazel building system. I am suspecting the file time-stamp is changed randomly?

Comment: which OS and which version of ninja are you using? There might be a problem with Windows file format in ninja below version 1.5.3

Comment: I use Ubuntu 16.04 and install ninja-build, the version is 1.7.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem with `ninja` and my GNU based toolchain. After a lot of trial and error I found that CMake/`ninja` scanned the standard include directories and sometimes concluded that those header files have changed.

So changing the dependency checking options to exclude system includes did solve this problem.

Add the following CMake code - probably with some changes for Clang - before your `project()` command or inside your toolchain file:

```
if (CMAKE_GENERATOR MATCHES "Ninja")
    file(
        WRITE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/GNUMakeRulesOverwrite.cmake" 
            "STRING(REPLACE \"-MD\" \"-MMD\" CMAKE_DEPFILE_FLAGS_C \"\${CMAKE_DEPFILE_FLAGS_C}\")\n"
            "STRING(REPLACE \"-MD\" \"-MMD\" CMAKE_DEPFILE_FLAGS_CXX \"\${CMAKE_DEPFILE_FLAGS_CXX}\")\n"
    )
    set(CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/GNUMakeRulesOverwrite.cmake" CACHE INTERNAL "")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to solve this issue for 2 days now. BIG BIG thanks to Florian, it is the only solution which worked for me. I am working on Windows 10 with CMake, Ninja (1.11) and the MinGW (11.4) compiler kit, using VS code. If this somewhat resembles you current setup, try pasting his block

```
if (CMAKE_GENERATOR MATCHES "Ninja")
    file(
        WRITE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/GNUMakeRulesOverwrite.cmake" 
            "STRING(REPLACE \"-MD\" \"-MMD\" CMAKE_DEPFILE_FLAGS_C \"\${CMAKE_DEPFILE_FLAGS_C}\")\n"
            "STRING(REPLACE \"-MD\" \"-MMD\" CMAKE_DEPFILE_FLAGS_CXX \"\${CMAKE_DEPFILE_FLAGS_CXX}\")\n"
    )
    set(CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/GNUMakeRulesOverwrite.cmake" CACHE INTERNAL "")
endif()
```

into your CMakeLists.txt, after your cmake_minimum_required() line, but before your project() line. On my setup, It worked immediately.